# how to boot into ubuntu/server that's in the same disk as windows 8

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8.1, multi-boot, ubuntu-server

so I got windows 8.1 installed and then I installed ubuntu 14.04.1, rebooted and it still boots into windows 8.1. 
how to boot into ubuntu not windows and how to make it happen by default

Answer (score 0):

By default when you install Ubuntu from a live USB or live CD, Grub bootloader is installed into the MBR. At installation, Grub finds the OS present in the partitions of your drive and offers you the choice at booting time which one to boot.

A possible explanation why it did not happen with your installation is if you unchecked the option to install the bootloader. There are several ways to repair such a situation, but perhaps the easiest is to repeat the Ubuntu installation, and allow it to install the bootloader this time.

Comment: In ubuntu 14.04 i didn't even see that option